# How can I get the golden egg in level 1-8 of Angry Birds?

Tags: macos, angry-birds

Is it actually possible to get the golden egg in level 1-8 in Angry Birds on Mac? My mouse is stuck with the catapult and I can't click the chest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to type Open, noting the capital O

Comment: I finally figured this out! You have to hold the shift key and then type "open".

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a trackpad just type OPEN (not case-sensitive) on keyboard. If you're using a mouse left-click the hand cursor on the treasure chest, hold the click and then type OPEN.